# Apache-Camel SQLEndpoint - configure a custom BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using camel version 3.14.5 and I'm wondering if there's a way (I can't see one) where I can use a custom`BeanPropertyRowMapper` when using a `SqlEndpoint`.

I'm using the sql endpoint like this in a route:

```
.to("mySqlComponent:classpath:my_sql.sql?outputType=StreamList&outputClass=com.my.project.MyCustomMappedPojo")
```

Looking at the code it does look like a BeanPropertyRowMapper is hardcoded in the class

> DefaultSqlEndpoint

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ResultSetIterator queryForStreamList(Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        if (outputClass == null) {
            RowMapper rowMapper = new ColumnMapRowMapper();
            return new ResultSetIterator(connection, statement, rs, rowMapper);
        } else {
            Class<?> outputClzz = getCamelContext().getClassResolver().resolveClass(outputClass);
            RowMapper rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper(outputClzz);
            return new ResultSetIterator(connection, statement, rs, rowMapper);
        }
    }
```

So all I'm after is a way to make use of a Custom RowMapper.

The most obvious way would be to pass it to the SqlEndpoint directly, but there's no such property.

Alternatively I thought about using a custom `SqlEndpoint` whilst wiring a `SqlComponent` in Spring, but I see that the `SqlComponent` uses a `SqlEndpoint` hardcoded (i.e.: doesn't allow me to inject a custom Endpoint) which in turns uses the hardcoded BeanPropertyRowMapper as per the code sample above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have a custom `org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper` ?

Its not possible to configure currently in camel-sql.
You are welcome to create a JIRA and work on a PR to add support for this.

Comment: I just override the underscore method so I have more flexibility on the column name/alias mappings that is all.

Comment: I created a JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-19211